# Tableview rows are not showing inorder with added values in swift

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, rows

I am getting JSON response in profile view controller.. initially JSON contains one address which i need to show in tableview and then i am adding new addresses from thirdviewcontroller to first viewcontroller JSON...

now both initial address and all added new address i need to update in profile viewcontroller INORDER.. how?

**if i add like below in profileviewcontroller then tableview not showing in order with address**: here the initial address going down and added new address also scattered..... i need initial address to be at index 0 and new address to be at index 1...

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController, MyCellDelegate {

@IBOutlet var addressTableview: UITableView!
var userModel : ProfileModel?

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden=true
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.getUserProfile()
    }
}

func getUserProfile() {

    let urlStr = urlComponents?.url
    
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: urlStr!, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
            if httpResponse!.statusCode == 200 {
                do {
                    let jsonObject  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableLeaves) as! [String :AnyObject]
                    self.userModel = ProfileModel.init(fromDictionary: jsonObject)
                    if (self.userModel?.userId) != nil {
                      
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.addressTableview.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                } catch { print(error.localizedDescription) }
            
    })
    dataTask.resume()
}

}
extension ProfileViewController : UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    return userModel?.userAddresses.count ?? 0
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
    let cell: AddresCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddresCell", for: indexPath) as! AddresCell
    
    let addr = userModel?.userAddresses![indexPath.row]
    
        cell.name.text    = addr?.type
        cell.typeAddLabel.text = addr?.addressName
                  let street = addr?.streetName
                  let colony = addr?.colony
                  let city   = addr?.city
                   let pincode = addr?.pincode
        let locality: String = addr?.buildingName ?? ""
        let dorNum: String = addr?.houseNo ?? ""
        cell.address.text = street! + "," + colony! + "," + city! + "," + pincode! + "," + locality + "," + dorNum
        return cell
    }
    }
```

where i am wrong, how do i make tableview rows in order, please don't mind i got stuck here fro long time

**this is ProfileModel code:**

```
 class ProfileModel  : NSObject, NSCoding{

var userId : String!

var userAddresses : [ProfileModelUserAddress]!

init(fromDictionary dictionary: [String:Any]){
    userId = dictionary["userId"] as? String
    userAddresses = [ProfileModelUserAddress]()
    if let userAddressesArray = dictionary["userAddresses"] as? [[String:Any]]{
        for dic in userAddressesArray{
            let value = ProfileModelUserAddress(fromDictionary: dic)
            userAddresses.append(value)
        }
    }
}
func toDictionary() -> [String:Any]
{
    var dictionary = [String:Any]()
    if userId != nil{
        dictionary["userId"] = userId
    }
    if userAddresses != nil{
        var dictionaryElements = [[String:Any]]()
        for userAddressesElement in userAddresses {
            dictionaryElements.append(userAddressesElement.toDictionary())
        }
        dictionary["userAddresses"] = dictionaryElements
    }
    return dictionary
}
@objc required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    userId = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "userId") as? String
    userAddresses = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "userAddresses") as? [ProfileModelUserAddress]
}
@objc func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)
{
    if userId != nil{
        aCoder.encode(userId, forKey: "userId")
    }
    if userAddresses != nil{
        aCoder.encode(userAddresses, forKey: "userAddresses")
    }
}
}
```

**code for ProfileModel's `var userAddresses : [ProfileModelUserAddress]`:**

```
class ProfileModelUserAddress : NSObject, NSCoding{

var addressId : String!
var addressName : String!
var userId : String!
var pincode : String!
var city : String!
var streetName : String!

init(fromDictionary dictionary: [String:Any]){
    addressId = dictionary["addressId"] as? String
    addressName = dictionary["addressName"] as? String
    userId = dictionary["userId"] as? String
    pincode = dictionary["pincode"] as? String
    city = dictionary["city"] as? String
    streetName = dictionary["streetName"] as? String
    
}
func toDictionary() -> [String:Any]
{
    var dictionary = [String:Any]()
    if addressId != nil{
        dictionary["addressId"] = addressId
    }
    if addressName != nil{
        dictionary["addressName"] = addressName
    }
    if userId != nil{
        dictionary["userId"] = userId
    }
    if pincode != nil{
        dictionary["pincode"] = pincode
    }
    if city != nil{
        dictionary["city"] = city
    }
    if streetName != nil{
        dictionary["streetName"] = streetName
    }
    
    return dictionary
}
@objc required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    addressId = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "addressId") as? String
    addressName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "addressName") as? String
    userId = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "userId") as? String
    pincode = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "pincode") as? String
    city = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "city") as? String
    streetName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "streetName") as? String
  
}
@objc func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)
{
    if addressId != nil{
        aCoder.encode(addressId, forKey: "addressId")
    }
    if addressName != nil{
        aCoder.encode(addressName, forKey: "addressName")
    }
    if userId != nil{
        aCoder.encode(userId, forKey: "userId")
    }
    if pincode != nil{
        aCoder.encode(pincode, forKey: "pincode")
    }
    if city != nil{
        aCoder.encode(city, forKey: "city")
    }
    if streetName != nil{
        aCoder.encode(streetName, forKey: "streetName")
    }
}
}
```

**from this viewcontroller i am adding new address to profileviewcontroller tableview:**

```
 class NewZoomAddressViewController: UIViewController {

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
let center = getCenterLocation(for: mapView)
let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()

guard let previousLocation = self.latestLocation else { return }

guard center.distance(from: previousLocation) > 50 else { return }
self.previousLocation = center

let userLocation :CLLocation = center as CLLocation
latitudeZoom = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
logitudeZoom = userLocation.coordinate.longitude

geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(center) { [weak self] (placemarks, error) in
    guard let self = self else { return }
    self.streetNumber = placemark.subThoroughfare ?? ""
    self.streetName = placemark.thoroughfare ?? ""
    self.localityName = placemark.locality ?? ""//locality
    self.sublocalityName = placemark.subLocality ?? ""//locality
    self.zipName = placemark.postalCode ?? ""//locality
    
}
}



@IBAction func popupSubmitBtn(_ sender: Any) {

if addressTextfield != nil{
    self.saveaddAddressService()
}
}

func saveaddAddressService(){

let parameters: [String: Any] = [
                 "pincode": zipName,
                 "city": localityName,
                 "streetName": sublocalityName,
                 "colony": "",
                 "location" : locations,
                 "addressName" : addressTextfield.text
             ]

         do {
              let jsonObject  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableLeaves) as! [String: Any]
              print("saved address json \(jsonObject)")

              self.addAddrsID = jsonObject["addressId"] as! String
                        
              UserDefaults.standard.set(self.addAddrsID, forKey: "addAddress")
             DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewController") as! ProfileViewController
                            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
                }
              
                } catch { print(error.localizedDescription) }
                } else {

                }
            }
        })
        dataTask.resume()
    }
 }
```

**profileviewcontroller json response: same userid for all address.. but for every new address there will be new addressid**

```
    {
    addressId = 5ef48787f546e73ee823f032;
    addressName = ban;
    
    city = Bengaluru;
    dateCreated = "25-06-2020 16:46:23";
    dateModified = "25-06-2020 16:46:23";
    pincode = 560001;
   
    userId = 85dc157688d84aab9bbbab150cbc13da;
    },
   {
    addressId = 5ef48828f546e73ee823f033;
    addressName = chen;
    dateCreated = "25-06-2020 16:49:04";
    landMark = "";
   
    pincode = 600095;
    streetName = Maduravoyal;
    userId = 85dc157688d84aab9bbbab150cbc13da;
   },
   {
    addressId = 5ef46670f546e73ee823f020;
    addressName = vizag;
    
    city = Visakhapatnam;
    colony = "";
    dateCreated = "25-06-2020 14:25:12";
    
    pincode = 530045;
   
    userId = 85dc157688d84aab9bbbab150cbc13da;
     },
     {
    addressId = 5ef4664af546e73ee823f01c;
```

Comment: Can you show the `userModel`. Maybe you can add another variable `addedAt` in the model and the sort the array based on that variable

Comment: This is your third almost identical question. Even this question cannot be answered without more information. What is `updateUserDetails()`? What is the model? How are you *adding new addresses from thirdviewcontroller to first ViewController*?

Comment: @vadian.. i have edited my post with all releated code.. `updateUserDetails()` is not related to tableview.. please have a look

Comment: @Mat..i have edited my post with all userModel.. please take a look and do help

Comment: @vadian any suggestions.. where i am wrong

Comment: @swiftIOS you said there is one address when the app first load, then users can add more and you want them ordered on the same way users added the. Why is that? Is it always the case? Do you fetch data from your API? Do you have access to the database?

Comment: @vadian, yes i am passing values in `let parameters: [String: Any] = [
                            "pincode": zipName,
                            "city": localityName,
                            "streetName": sublocalityName,`  so the address is adding in profileviewcontroller response

Comment: @vadian so how to show them in order, please let me know

Comment: @Mat yes initially  profileVC url response contains one address  so tableview inatially with one address.. after i am adding address in `NewZoomAddressViewController `  which i need to add in 2nd place.. and other address in 3rd place in tableview

Comment: @vadian all `NewZoomAddressViewController ` added address coming in `profileviewcontroller` url response.. which i need to show in order

Comment: @Mat, profileVC url response initially contains one address... if i add new address from `NewZoomAddressViewController ` then the address is adding in `profilevc ` url response.. which i need to show inorder.. for every new address the addressid is changing

Comment: @Mat, i have edited my post with profileVC url response.. pls have a look

Comment: @vadian, i have edited my question with profileVC url response.. pls have a look..and do help

Comment: @vadian for every new address in `NewZoomAddressViewController` getting new `addressId` with that ID need to show tableview inorder

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand the code. Where does `data` come from in `NewZoomAddressViewController`? And where is the `dataTask`? And – once again –you create `let string...` and `jsonObject` and then you dismiss the controller with this horrible syntax and `string` and  `jsonObject` are thrown away. I'm out.

Comment: @swiftIOS `dateCreated` is added every time your user adds a new address? Is the address created by each user or once the address is created, other users can use the same data? If that his the case, create another table that holds the relationship between addresses and users. In that table, you can have a row `dateCreated` . You can then join the tables and fetch `dateCreated` in your app model. After that it is easy.

Comment: @Mat.. one user only adding new address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model to `ProfileModelUserAddress` add a new variable to hold the `dateCreated`:

```
class ProfileModelUserAddress : NSObject, NSCoding{

    // add this variable
    var dateCreated : Date!
    //.... your other variables 

    init(fromDictionary dictionary: [String:Any]){
       let formatter = DateFormatter()

       formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
       //convert your string to date
       dateCreated = formatter.date(from: dictionary["dateCreated"] as! String)
       //....the rest of your code
    }
}
```

Then in your `ProfileViewController`

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController, MyCellDelegate {

   var userModel : ProfileModel?
   // added this array which will hold all your addresses 
   var addressModel =  [ProfileModelUserAddress]()

   func getUserProfile() {
      // if you call this fucntion again everytime you add 
      // a new address, call removeAll() in order to have an 
      //empty array, otherwise you will end up with double values.
      self.addressModel.removeAll()
      //.... rest of your code

      let jsonObject  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableLeaves) as! [String :AnyObject]
      self.userModel = ProfileModel.init(fromDictionary: jsonObject)
         for address in userModel!.userAddresses! {
            addressModel.append(address)
         }
     self.addressModel.sort(by: { $0.dateCreated!.compare($1.dateCreated!) == .orderedDescending})
      //.....
      //.... rest of your code
   }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     // rest of your code ....
     // You can use your addresses array
     let addr = self.addressModel[indexPath.row]
     // rest of your code ....
  }

}
```

I tested it and it works:

```
func getUserProfile() {
   // All dictionaries have the same values except for the date
   let address1 = ["addressId" : "5ef48828f546e73ee823f033", "addressName": "chen","dateCreated": "25-06-2020 16:49:04", "landMark": "", "pincode": "879327" ,"streetName": "Maduravoyal", "userId": "947384783749" ]
   let address2 = ["addressId" : "5ef48828f546e73ee823f033", "addressName": "chen","dateCreated": "27-06-2020 16:49:04", "landMark": "", "pincode": "879327" ,"streetName": "Maduravoyal", "userId": "947384783749" ]
   let address3 = ["addressId" : "5ef48828f546e73ee823f033", "addressName": "chen","dateCreated": "25-06-2020 19:49:04", "landMark": "", "pincode": "879327" ,"streetName": "Maduravoyal", "userId": "947384783749" ]
   let address4 = ["addressId" : "5ef48828f546e73ee823f033", "addressName": "chen","dateCreated": "29-06-2020 19:49:04", "landMark": "", "pincode": "879327" ,"streetName": "Maduravoyal", "userId": "947384783749" ]

   let addressObj = ProfileModelUserAddress.init(fromDictionary: address1)
   let addressObj1 = ProfileModelUserAddress.init(fromDictionary: address2)
   let addressObj2 = ProfileModelUserAddress.init(fromDictionary: address3)
   let addressObj3 = ProfileModelUserAddress.init(fromDictionary: address4)

   var addresseTry = [ProfileModelUserAddress]()
   addresseTry.append(addressObj)
   addresseTry.append(addressObj1)
   addresseTry.append(addressObj2)
   addresseTry.append(addressObj3)
      for address in addresseTry {
         addressModel.append(address)
      }

   self.addressModel.sort(by: { $0.dateCreated!.compare($1.dateCreated!) == .orderedDescending})
   
      for addressForDate in self.addressModel {
         print(addressForDate.dateCreated)
      }
}
```

which prints:

```
Optional(2020-06-29 16:49:04 +0000)
Optional(2020-06-27 13:49:04 +0000)
Optional(2020-06-25 16:49:04 +0000)
Optional(2020-06-25 13:49:04 +0000)
```

Comment: thank you, addresses are adding inorder but if i go to otherviewcontroller and coming back then same address array adding twice in tableview

Comment: Do call getUserProfile again after you add a new address?

Comment: @swiftIOS check the updated answer. Tr to use         `self.addressModel.removeAll()` if you pull again data from your server after users add  new addresses.

Comment: yes now its working.. is there any other way apart from datesort.. can we sort `addressId`?